# *Vectorized* way to find indices of minimums for each column (excluding all already found indices)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following square DataFrame:

```
In [104]: d
Out[104]:
           a          b          c          d          e
a        inf   5.909091   8.636364   7.272727   4.454545
b   7.222222        inf   8.666667   7.666667   1.777778
c  15.833333  13.000000        inf   9.166667  14.666667
d   4.444444   3.833333   3.055556        inf   4.833333
e  24.500000   8.000000  44.000000  43.500000        inf
```

this is modified distance matrix, representing pairwise distance between objects ['a','b','c','d','e'], where each row is divided by a coefficient (weight) and all diagonal elements artificially set to `np.inf`.

How may I get a list/vector of indices like as follows in an *efficient* (*vectorized*) way:

```
d   # index of minimal element in the column `a`
a   # index of minimal element in the column `b` (excluding already found indices: [d]) 
b   # index of minimal element in the column `c` (excluding already found indices: [d,a]) 
c   # index of minimal element in the column `d` (excluding already found indices: [d,a,b])
```

I.e. in the first column we had found index `d`, so when we search for a minimum in the second column  we are excluding row with index `d` (found previously in the first column) - this would be `a`.

When we are looking for the minimum in the third column we are excluding rows with indices found previously (`['d','a']`) - this would be `b`.

When we are looking for the minimum in the fourth column we are excluding rows with indices found previously (`['d','a','b']`) - this would be `c`.

I don't need diagonal (`inf`) elements, so the resulting list/vector will contain `d.shape[0] - 1` elements.

---

I.e. the resulting list will look like: `['d','a','b','c']` or in case of Numpy solution the corresponding numerical indices: `[3,0,1,2]`

It's not a problem to do it using slow `for loop` solution, but I can't wrap my head around a vectorized (fast) solution...

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by `excluding already found indices:`?

Comment: There is a typo in the third line of the expected output, it should be `b`, I imagine (the next line actually shows `b` as an already found index). I assume the minimal element of column `e` is not shown/needed because it can be determined by exclusion? Anyway, I'm not sure there _can_ be a vectorized solution, there is a hard dependency with the result of the previous column...

Comment: @jdehesa, yeah, tanks a lot! I've corrected it now...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i've updated my question with a short explanation...

Comment: Based on your updated solution, this is how I understand it: "the result of the current step depends on the results of the previous". I cannot think of a way to do this without a loop :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop is the only solution I can see here.

But you can use `numpy` + `numba` to optimise.

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def get_min_lookback(A, res):
    for i in range(A.shape[1]):
        res[i] = np.argmin(A[:, i])
        A[res[i], :] = np.inf
    return res

arr = df.values

get_min_lookback(arr, np.zeros(arr.shape[1], dtype=int))

# array([3, 0, 1, 2, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, which I'm sure is not the best one:

resulting list:

```
res = []
```

main function, that will search for a minimum in a column, excluding previously found indices and adding found index to `res`:

```
def f(col):
    ret = col.loc[~col.index.isin(res)].idxmin()
    if ret not in res:
        res.append(ret)
```

apply function to each column:

```
_ = d.apply(f)
```

result:

```
In [55]: res
Out[55]: ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

excluding last element:

```
In [56]: res[:-1]
Out[56]: ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```